# switch from the $get method to $POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

OK this "should" be a simple code but i got really stuck on this...
I usually deal with forms that uses the $GET method, but for this one i need to go with the $POST.... so i want to take this code and put it into a $Post

```
    $display_string .= "<th><a href='Details.php?ID=".$row[ID]."'>".$row[Name]."</a>";
```

This is a line from a dynamic table that i am fetching data from using ajax, but i then want to take this user data and fill a user_Detail page....using the $POST

Can anyone trow me a line here????

Thanks

Comment: If you are using jQuery as your tagging shows, you should consider using $.ajax or $.post from jQuery

Comment: i already got this data from ajax, but i need to go to another different page, when i click the hyperlink made on users name...

Comment: what data do you want to pass to this page over post? rowId and rowName?

Comment: This `$row[ID]` means `ID` is a constant, `$row['ID']` means, ID is a string, it's 2 difference things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links aren't supposed to send POST requests. Anyways, you can do it by using a hidden form and a link that triggers a javascript.

```
$display_string .= "<th><form action='Details.php' id='detailsForm". $row['ID'] ."' name='detailsForm' method='POST'><input type=hidden name='ID' value='" . $row['ID'] ."'></form><a href='#' onclick=\"document.getElementById('detailsForm". $row['ID'] ."').submit();\">". $row['Name'] ."</a>";
```

Should do the trick. Create a form, insert the value you want to submit in a hidden input field and the link triggers the form to be submitted onclick.

EDIT: If you meant ID and Name to be a constant, of course you have to write $row[ID] and $row[Name] instead of $row['ID'] and $row['Name'].

EDIT: so give every form a unique ID (like the $row['ID'] and tell the javascript to submit exactly this form.

Comment: i'm using a combo box to make a query and then send this data with ajax...but when i click the link it sends the first request(from ajax)??? i even change the var name in the form...

Comment: Ah, yeah, with this solution, you create many forms. I'll update the answer I a few minutes with a solution wich generates Mordmore and different forms.

Comment: updated my answer to generate one unique form per row, but I have to notice, that this is really not beautiful! But for your purpose, this should work now.

Comment: ok this really work, thank alot, know trying to beautify the thing...;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a form then.

```
<form action="Details.php" name="display_string" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="$display_string" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did it do what you expected?

Comment: my problem here is that i have a table with users name and hyperlinked with the data i want to $post to another page... and when i try to do this only last users data goes to the other page....